# Scrolling to bottom elements of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have prepared a pretty self-explaining jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nt7xzxur/ with the following scrolling code inside:

```
function smoothScroll(hash) {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
}, 750);
```

When you click on one of the links available, the browser's window is scrolled to the point where the corresponding item on the right side is located. There's one thing I would like to achieve though:

Obviously last two items won't scroll up to the top because there's not enough content below them for scrolling. **I would like for ALL items to be scrollable to the top** and so far I haven't found a good way to do it. I could add some blank lines below the last item, but it adds length to the right scroll bar and is not very elegant.

Is there any other way to make it happen through css, js or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically calculate the extra space and add this to end of the page. I have created one small code you can look at it and use it according to your need  http://jsbin.com/mubugusido/6/edit?html,js

Comment: That's actually pretty clever, the best solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

This will add extra space at the bottom of your .main div:

```
wH = $(window).height();
$extraH = $('<div></div>').height(wH);
$('.main').append($extraH);
```

Or you could add a min-height to .main and set it to some amount to guarantee there's enough space.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way you can achieve this is to actually add some content at the bottom.

You cannot get the page to scroll to the top of the Fifth Item because there isn't anything below to display, because the page has ended.